# "fallen lassen und aufheben" how to use the right word?

Tags: meaning

how ist right way to say "pick up".

1. Ich lasse mein Buch fallen. Das Buch ist runtergefallen. Ich hebe das Buch auf. (i pick up the book)

Would you say that? or what word is more common?

thank you!!!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note that "runterfallen" is colloquial. In written language we use "herunterfallen".

Answer (score 5):

First off: your usage of "aufheben" for *to pick up* is correct.

Notice, though, that "runterfallen" is colloquial and you shouldn't use it in written documents. There are "herunterfallen" and "hinunterfallen". Both describe the act of something falling down and the difference is quite subtle. Also, there is no counterpart in English for this specific difference. Both would be translated by "to fall down".

"herunterfallen" means the falling object is moving towards you (the observer) or your level respectively. e.g. consider you standing on earth and you watch something falling down from the sky. You would describe this as:

> Ich beobachte, wie etwas (vom Himmel) *herunter*fällt.

On the other hand, if you are standing at the top of a building and you have just thrown something out the window:

> Ich beobachte, wie etwas *hinunter*fällt.

If you are at the same level (like something falling off the table and you standing besides) you can use either.

In general, (in combinations with words of movement) "her-" means in a direction towards you, "hin-" means in a direction away from you. We passing a ball to and fro would be:

> Ich werfe den Ball zu dir *hin*.
> Du wirfst den Ball zu mir *her*.